# Push all Index Defs to RavenDB from a single file

Tags: ravendb, disaster-recovery

In RavenDB a curl command on `ravenServer.com/databases/myApp/indexes` 
returns a nice list of all index definitions for the database.

For my disaster recovery scenario, is there a http command that can put them all back.  Or will I have to parse each one out and issue the command outlined in the documentation?

My app is using the `HttpApi` and not using .Net to create indexes, or I would just push them all that way.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to create them one at a time.
Note that you can use the smuggler tool, which will do this for you.
It is a command line app that comes with RavenDB.